# License Agreement for Snowflake JDBC Driver

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to locate the license agreement for the Snowflake JDBC driver.  Can anyone point me to this?

Answer (score 0):

It's "Apache License 2.0"

https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-jdbc/blob/master/LICENSE.txt